# How to enable google chrome chrome://flags/ values using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to enable google chrome flags enable using JavaScript.If flags enable then no action require, if disable then  make it  enable .

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do that using JavaScript without the user knowing.

Comment: This is usually locked down. You have to tell the user how to enable it.

Comment: I don't agree with the close reason. This is not a question about *general computing hardware and software*, it's about how to program something with Javascript. Althogh the answer probably is that this won't be possible, it does not make the question off-topic.

Comment: `Panchotiya Vipul` needs it using Javascript, it doesn't belongs to any `general computing hardware and software` to mark question as Off-topic.

Answer (score 10):

**local state** file contains setting of flags(This is text file in json format)

[Chrome user directory location](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)

```
"browser": {
      "enabled_labs_experiments": [ "load-cloud-policy-on-signin", "old-checkbox-style" ],
      "last_redirect_origin": ""
   }
```

**"enabled_labs_experiments"** attribute contains value of such flags which user enabled manually.In your case you have to first check your preferred flag entry is available or not if not then you have to add your flag in this file by javascript.

Using javascript you can read and edit text files so read that file from specified location as per operating system and edit that file.

Comment: attempt to read local file such as chrome's Local State results in "SecurityError"

Answer (score 5):

Changing browser settings and options using Javascript is not possible. This can only be controlled by the user.

However, [Chrome's experimental flags can be accessed using direct links](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/05/21/chromes-experimental-flags-are-now-accessible-via-direct-links/). But note that

> The feature is currently available in Chrome Canary, and maybe also in Chrome Dev. It may take a while before it makes its way to other versions of the browser.

Once it is available, you can use a link like this in your webpage to make it more convenient for the user to find the right setting:

```
<a href="chrome://flags/#disable-webrtc" target="_blank">Enable WEBRTC</a>
```

Comment: The direct link works when pasted on the browser navigation bar. but fails when linking through the page ( cannot access the local resource error )

Comment: @sreekarun are you using Chrome Canary? As written, it is only available in Chrome Canary and maybe in Chrome Dev currently, not in the stable version.

Comment: I'm using v53 beta and it still doesn't allow linking to `chrome://` from an `<a>` element.