# Kendo Drag & Drop doesn't seem to work in Chrome on Surface Pro 3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a simple Kendo grid with drag & drop. JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/76sLggyL/11/). Dragging and dropping rows works on Chrome everywhere except on co-worker's Surface Pro 3.  I've uninstalled all extensions, mouse software, etc...basically down to barebones, but drag&drop won't even start, e.g. `dragstart` event never fires.

```
grid.table.find("tbody tr").kendoDraggable({
     dragstart: function() { ... }
```

The only way to start the drag is to click into the cell and put it into editable mode, which is not the way I want users to drag & drop.

I am starting to think that it's a Surface Pro 3 issue.  Can someone (preferably with Surface Pro 3) check it out?

P.S.  It works perfectly fine on Firefox on the Surface Pro 3.

Answer (score 3):

Its an issue in Chrome because it has support for touch events. The Microsoft Surface is detected as a touch capable device, so chrome enables touch events.

Unfortunately there is no drag and drop support in most, if not all, mobile (touch) browsers. Assumingly Chrome switches to some kind of mode that also disables the HTML5 drag and drop.

You can activate a mode where drag and drop can be initiated by touch and hold on an element:

- goto chrome://flags/#enable-touch-drag-drop

Alternatively there are other flags for deactivating the touch support completeley: chrome://flags/#touch-events

Comment: Is there a way to enable these flags from my Javascript code?  Just for my page?

Comment: Unfortunately no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951644/how-to-enable-google-chrome-chrome-flags-values-using-javascript but maybe this does help you out: https://github.com/timruffles/ios-html5-drag-drop-shim